How to Resolve the Issue of the ‘Distribute App’ Button Being Disabled for App Store Distribution

I’m having trouble with distributing my app to the App Store.
I’ve successfully created an archive, but the “Distribute App” button is disabled and I can’t click it. What steps should I take to resolve this issue and proceed with distribution?
I also tried to use real phone for archive

How come nothing is shown as selected? What happens when you tap on an entry? You could could also try enabling the column that shows the Status (or scrolling it into view).

It is same when i tapped one thing in list

So when you tap an entry, does it become selected (in other words, get a blue background)? And what is the Status of the entry?

Can you try again with a different value for the Version and Build numbers than the previous version?
